# Are favorite tags gone

Tags: support, tag-watching, new-nav

Here on meta wondering about favorite/saved tags. I do not see my favorite tags in the nav on SO anymore.  This was a favorite feature of mine is it going away or can anyone shed some light on this feature's future?

Thanks

Comment: You were probably using "new nav" which [has been turned off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359643/retiring-new-navigation-beta-in-preparation-for-navigation-3-0).

Comment: But it is still not there, I still have no saved tags and cannot see where to re add them, or is it paused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a feature of [New Navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308875/4946380). However, as of December 4, 2017, [New Navigation has been *temporarily* retired](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359643/4946380). You will, unfortunately, no longer see your tags in the navigation anymore.

However, they are only being retired so that Stack Overflow the company can **work on better nav tools**. Jon Ericson states in the question announcing the retirement that you *will* see tools coming; just probably not tabs:

> We probably won’t use the tab interface again (it gets crowded quickly), but we do want to make it easy for you to jump to the tags you care about.

So, your tabs are gone, but they will be replaced by something better in the future.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not gone.

You can still see, and edit, the list of your favorite tags in the right sidebar on the following pages:

- The site's homepage
- The site's /questions tab (any filter)
- Every tag page showing the tag's questions

For example:

> [image: right sidebar with favorite tags]

They are right there, below the Community Bulletin box.

If you don't see that sidebar, it means you did something to hide it, e.g. userscript or custom stylesheet, maybe to avoid seeing ads or the Hot Network Questions, but that's not SE fault.

Another place you can see and edit the list is the [Preferences tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) in the profile edit section.